# Limit the api functional by roles with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to implement SpringSecurity mechanism on my project. I have two roles: MEMBER and ADMIN. Both MEMBER and ADMIN can access to api update user, example. MEMBER can only change the name, avatar, ADMIN can change anything. How can I apply the SpringSecurity concept to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You would would need to start off with providing two different users with each of these roles. For example, the following would provide an [in memory representation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-inmemory) of the user `member` and `admin` each with the password `password`:

```
@Bean
static InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
    UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
        .username("member")
            .password("password")
            .roles("MEMBER")
            .build();
    UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Now you can setup the [authorization rules](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authorization-filtersecurityinterceptor). For URLs that you want either role to work, you can use `hasAnyRole(...)` and for URLs you only want to work with the admin you can use `hasRole(...)`. For example, the following would allow either user to use the URLs `/user/name` or `/user/avatar` but the admin can do any URL that starts with `/user/**`. All other URLs are rejected.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/user/name", "/user/avatar").hasAnyRole("MEMBER", "ADMIN")
                .mvcMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().denyAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
}
```

It is important to note that only the first rule will be used for authorization. So while `/user/name` matches the rule `/user/name`, `/user/**' (starts with` /user/`), and` anyRequest()`only the first rule of`hasAnyRole("MEMBER", "ADMIN")` will be used.

You can also setup rules that take advantage of the HTTP method. For example, the following would allow `MEMBER` or `ADMIN` for HTTP GET on `/user/address`

```
.mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/address").hasAnyRole("MEMBER", "ADMIN")
```

An alternative approach is to assign your users multiple roles. For example, the admin user might have the roles `MEMBER` and `ADMIN`.

```
@Bean
static InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager() {
    UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
        .username("member")
            .password("password")
            .roles("MEMBER")
            .build();
    UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN", "MEMBER")
            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

Then your rules can be simplified to having a single role on the URLs.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .mvcMatchers("/user/name", "/user/avatar").hasRole("MEMBER")
                .mvcMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().denyAll()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
}
```

This approach can be preferable when you have lots of roles to think about. Each operation is a single role, but users may have more than one role.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but the params are in the body request. My api is only: $SERVER_HOST:$PORT/api/user